# My.sln - build configurations - project keeps reappearing

Tags: visual-studio

The solution I'm working on has multiple build/platoform configuration.

I have added a project that I want to build only in two combinations: `Conf1_Debug/Any CPU` and `SolutionConf1_Rlease/Any CPU`.

If I go to the Configuration Manager and remove the project from let's say `Conf2_Release/ARM` the only difference I see is that 2 lines are removed from `*.sln`:

```
{GUID_HERE}.Conf2_Release|ARM.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
{GUID_HERE}.Conf2_Release|ARM.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
```

However, if I close Visual Studio and remove the lines myself then upon reopening the solution the configurations are back in the `*.sln` file.

I have cleaned my get repo and searched `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio` to see any files that may instruct Visual Studio to add the project in all configurations, but I cannot find anything.

How does Visual Studio establish a given project is part of the given Solutio Configuration + Solution Platform combination?

Comment: Have you also looked in the .vcxproj files in addition to the .sln file ?

Comment: It is not that clean, the IDE assumes too much about Debug/Release being present.  You strongly favor using the checkbox to prevent a project from getting built.

Comment: Thanks Hans, but I'm not sure I understand "You strongly favor". Do you mean that UI (as opposed to file modification direclty) is the safest way? If so I agree, but I'm after something that would work for me and our setup uses only Debug and Release **project** configurations. Having said that, it seems that removing `Build` lines would work even with non-standard **project** build configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contradictory to what the question states, only one line is removed if the project is removed via Configuration Manager:

`{GUID_HERE}.Conf2_Release|ARM.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU`

## Solution

### Summary

Remove `Build` lines and keep `ActiveCfg` lines.

`{GUID_HERE}.Conf2_Release|ARM.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU`

### Steps

My procedure is now:

1. Create the project.
2. Open .sln and find the project's GUID
3. `cat MySolution.sln | grep --invert-match '09F3C3BA-62A4-4CE8-A533-533C746B221B.*Build' > tmpfile ; rm MySolution.sln; mv tmpfile MySolution.sln`
4. Reload the solution
5. Add the project only to the desired configuration combinations.